# setState an array of Objects updating two values in the Object accordingly of the id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to target the specific object with the id an change the name and the email value together in one setState.(The members will take new objects with different id)

```
 state = {
      groupName:"",
      members: [
          {name:"", email:"", id:uuid.v4()}
      ]
  }  


  render(){
    return(
        {this.state.members.map((member) => {
              return (
                  <div key={member.id}>
                      <TextField

                          id={member.id}
                          placeholder="Enter your name..."
                          onChange={(event) => this.handleInput(event)} />
                      <TextField

                          id={member.id}
                          placeholder="Enter your email"
                          onChange={(event) => this.handleInput(event )} 
                          />
                  </div>
              )
       })}
  )}



  handleInput = (event) => {
      const newGroup = {...this.state}
      const newElement = {...newGroup.members[event.target.id]}

      newElement[name] = event.target.value;
      newGroup.members[name] = newElement;

      this.setState({
          state : newGroup 
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the field value in order to set the correct element within the members object. Also while updating you can map over the members array and update the respective object and in `setState` you would pass the `members` as key.

```js
 state = {
        groupName:"",
        members: [
            {name:"", email:"", id:uuid.v4()}
        ]
    }  


    render(){
      return(
          {this.state.members.map((member) => {
            return (
                <div key={member.id}>
                    <TextField
                        id={member.id}
                        placeholder="Enter your name..."
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleInput(event, "name")} />
                    <TextField
                        id={member.id}
                        placeholder="Enter your email"
                        onChange={(event) => this.handleInput(event, "email" )} 
                        />
                </div>
            )
        })}
    )}



    handleInput = (event, name) => {
        event.persist();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            members : prevState.members.map((item) => {
              if (item.id = event.target.id) {
                  return {
                      ...item,
                      [name]: event.target.value
                  }
              } else {
                return item;
              }
           }) 
       }))
    }
```

Comment: This breaks [one of React's principle rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). If you're setting new state based on existing state, you **must** use the callback version of `setState`.

Comment: Thank you this is working.Although i have problem know when i try to add an other object because of the not unique key.                           **addPerson(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
            members: [...this.state.members, {name:"", email:"", id:uuid.v4()}]
        })
    }**   .                                                                                                            
 This is the first project a try to do on my own, i am new in React.js

Comment: I did not understand your question regarding addPerson, could you please clarify

Comment: There was a problem with the equality comparison, i found out the solution.Thank you for your help. It's working perfectly.@Shubham Khatri

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

This is because `state` should be immutable. You can do following:

```
this.setState(({members})=> {
  const updateMembers = members.map(member => {
          if (member.id === event.target.id) {
              return {
                  ... member,
                  [name]: event.target.value
              }
          } 
          return member;

       }) 
  return {members: updateMembers}
})
```

You can read more about immutability [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/immutability-in-array-of-objects-using-map-method-dd61584c7188)